# Custom ListView doen't show

Tags: android

Can someone tell me what mistake i am making while making a custom listview because it doesnt show any data when using a custom adapter. While it works on a simple arrayadapter i do't get it is there some mistake in my customly made adapter??

**This is the my main xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SubCategories"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/suitablecategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Services"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Spin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="8">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/SubListView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**This is my row item Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CustomListItemName"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:hint="Enter Price"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/CustomListItemPrice"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**This is my customly made adapter**

```
package application.fyp.com.myfypapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PriceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> items;

    public PriceListAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_price_listview,R.id.CustomListItemName,list);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = list;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_price_listview, parent,false);
        TextView  name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.CustomListItemName);
        EditText price = convertView.findViewById(R.id.CustomListItemPrice);
        String it = items.get(position);
        name.setText(it);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**This is my main class where i am intiallizing and setting the listview using the adapter**

```
package application.fyp.com.myfypapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SubCategories extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Spinner spinner;
    private ListView lv;
    private Button addsc;
    private PriceListAdapter priceadapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub_categories);

        spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spin);
        lv = findViewById(R.id.SubListView);

        List<String> subCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        subCategoryList.add("A");
        subCategoryList.add("B");
        subCategoryList.add("C");
        subCategoryList.add("D");
        priceadapter = new PriceListAdapter(SubCategories.this, subCategoryList);
        lv.setAdapter(priceadapter);



    }
```

Comment: I also tried using the Baseadapter but same problem cant get to show any thing using the customly made adapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you adapter, you must change following:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // return 0; // This is what you have now
    return this.items.size(); // This is what it must be
}
```

getCount method is intended to return the number of items in the list view.

Comment: lol thanks man that helps a lot but i still don't get it what if i dont use this getCount method because its just an override method doesnt needs to get implemented.

Comment: Here is the catch: if you had not overriden it, it would work correctly since ArrayAdapter defines the getCount correctly. But you had overriden it, so now it is your responsibility to correctly implement getCount(). Also, note that only ArrayAdapter allows not to override getCount (as far as I am aware).
P.S. Also, if an answer solves your issue, it is polite to mark it as "correct".

Comment: Yeah I did thanks man that saved me from hitting my head in the wall :D